# Scala: How to assign a function without parameters to a variable or a value?

Tags: scala

Demo1:

```
def double(d: Int) = d * 2
val myDouble: Int => Int = double
myDouble(3)
```

the demo can compile and run well, then

i define a function without parameter
Demo2:

```
def double2 = 2 * 2
val myDouble2: () => Int = double2 

 //the error message is:error: type mismatch;
 //found   : Int
 //required: () => Int
```

How can i assign a function without parameters to a value identifier, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell you why the compiler doesn't implicitly transforms the method to a function in case of methods which don't take a parameter, but you can make it explicit for him using the underscore:

```
scala> val myDouble2: () => Int = double2 _
myDouble2: () => Int = <function0>

scala> myDouble2()
res2: Int = 4
```

Another way would be to add parenthesis to the method declaration, this apparently gets correctly converted to a function on assignation:

```
scala> def double2() = 2 * 2
double2: ()Int

scala> val myDouble2: () => Int = double2 
myDouble2: () => Int = <function0>
```

Comment: Also it is possible to use: def double2 = () => 2 * 2

Answer (score 2):

i found a method to implement this as follows:

```
val myDouble2= double2 _
```

with 'Wildcard Operator'